# Cannot scp a file into gcloud: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, scp

I'm trying to copy a file into a compute instance using `gcloud` like this:

```
gcloud compute scp ./file.txt.bz2 root@instance-1:/home/mehran/
```

And I'm facing an error:

```
No zone specified. Using zone [us-central1-c] for instance: [instance-1].
root@###.###.###.###: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

I've also tested without root:

```
gcloud compute scp ./file.txt.bz2 instance-1:/home/mehran/
```

And facing the same error. This is in the case that I **can** `ssh` into the same instance without any issue:

```
gcloud compute ssh instance-1
```

Comment: Did you allow root login? By default it's deactivated and it should stay that way...

Comment: But I cannot `scp` with my non-root user as well

Comment: Did not see the line, sorry... Did you open the firewall rule? can you test a telnet on the ssh port?

Comment: The only firewall related items I see in the Google Console are for HTTP and HTTPS. Unless you mean from within the OS in which case I didn't touch anything. One more thing, I can ssh into the instance as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, my user does not have the write permission to the home folder! Even a `chmod 777` did not help. I ended up copying to `/tmp` folder and then pick it up from there!

For some reason, the ssh (web-based) and scp were using different users. That's why my scp user didn't have access to that folder. It was trying to write into another user's home folder.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this post seems solved, I had a similar issue: I could SSH into the instance but could not scp. Turns out the folder on my instance did not have read/write permissions so I could not copy (write) into that folder.

Give permissions:

`chmod 777 <folder-name>`

Copy file/folder to folder in instance:

`sudo gcloud compute scp <file-to-copy> <username>@<instance-name>:<folder-to-copy-to-which-requires-permissions> --zone <zone> --project <project-id>`